# Adjust height of a container based on content

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, hybrid-mobile-app

In my application, I have a Container(inner container) inside of a main container(outer container). The inner container has form data as below:

[image]

Please observe the top & bottom margin around inner container in the above image. When I submit the form, we are showing validation messages. Then because of more content, overflow of 8 pixels is happening as below.

[image]

**Instead of adding scroll bar**, can I **increase the size of the inner container** by **decreasing the margin around it**? Is there any widget or methodology to follow to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

Adding code that I have developed so far

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [
      Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
            end: Alignment(0.0, 1.0),
            colors: [Colors.indigo[900], Colors.blue],
            tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
          )),
          child: Center(
              child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
                        end: Alignment(0.0, 1.0),
                        colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.indigo[900]],
                        tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                      )),
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 50.0),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: new List.generate(
                            this.forms.length,
                            (index) => new FormSelector(this._changeForm,
                                form: forms[index])),
                      ),
                      this.getForm(this.forms)
                    ],
                  ))))
    ]);
  }
```

Please help me solve this.

Thank you...

Comment: Post the code of what you have done so far.

Comment: I added **SingleChildScrollView** to the parent to get scrollbar. I am not sure how I can achieve the above.

Comment: It is hard to tell what to do( and how to fix) without seeing the code of what you have done so far.

Comment: @void, I have added the required code. Can you please look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use the stack widget instead of containers because you can set the stacks to overlap and thus having little to no margin.

See the video below for how a stack works:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liEGSeD3Zt8&vl=en

Hope this fixes your problem :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using padding, try removing the padding, and specify in the `Column`

`mainAxisAlignemnt: MainAxisAlignment.center`

This way, the default behavior will be to place all the widgets at the center, so there will be space above and bellow them and the container. As the column grows, the space above and bellow will shrink.

Notice that without a scroll, this will still cause an overflow if the screen size isn't big enough.